# Checking first argument of a script if it is -e or -d

Tags: shell-script

I am writing a bash shell script at the moment and one of the specifications is that I need to print an error message if the first argument, $1, is not -e or -d, this is what I have done:

```
if [ "$1" != "-e" ] || [ "$1" != "-d" ]; then
        echo "Error: First argument must be either -e or -d"
        exit 1
fi
```

this does not seem to work however, as even if i used -e or -d for the first argument, this error message is still printed. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Just the logic of it :) if it's -d, it's not -e, so your test is backwards.

Comment: You want "not (`-d` or `-e`)", i.e. "not `-d` and not `-e`".  Voting to close as off-topic (typo).

Answer (score 1):

If `$1` is `-d`, the first condition is true. If `$1` is `-e`, the second condition is true. If it's anything else, both are true. Since you joined them with `||` (*or*), the *then* branch of the *if* is taken if either is true. Therefore, the *then* branch is always taken.

You need to use `if [ "$1" != "-e" ] && [ "$1" != "-d" ]` to take the *then* branch only if `$1` is not `-e` *and* is not `-d`.

Answer (score 1):

```
case $1 in
    -d) ;; # nothing to do
    -e) ;; # nothing to do
    *)
        echo 'Error: First argument must be either -e or -d' >&2
        exit 1
esac
```

This would trigger the `exit 1` if `$1` is anything other than `-d` or `-e`.

Alternatively, set a flag depending on the option used and the act on it (I tend to separate *parsing* the command line options from *acting* on them):

```
case $1 in
    -d) dflag=1 ;;
    -e) dflag=0 ;;
    *)
        echo 'Error: First argument must be either -e or -d' >&2
        exit 1
esac

# Getting here means:
#     - $1 was either -d or -e
#     - $dflag will show which one it was

if [ "$dflag" -eq 1 ]; then
    # act on -d option
else
    # act on -e option
fi
```

---

As [ilkkachu has already elucidated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500258/116858), your issue (apart from the missing double quote) is one of logic (boolean operations).  Above, I'm just showing another way of doing the operation. `case`...`esac` statements are often used to process command line options.